# HTTP proxy between a client and a server using apache camel jetty component

Tags: apache-camel, jetty, api-gateway

I am new to Apache Camel.

I am trying to create an HTTP proxy between a client and a server.

Specifically, I need to call all the rest APIs of the camunda engine through apache camel.

I am referring the following URLs:

```
https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/jetty-component.html

https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html
```

My code looks like this:

```
  @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

       from("jetty:http://localhost:8081/engine-rest?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                .to("jetty:http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/");
}
```

spring boot project pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jetty-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

When I run this code it shows error like:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:125) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:3313) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(AbstractCamelContext.java:3206) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(AbstractCamelContext.java:2992) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2790) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2643) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2606) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2448) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121) ~[camel-spring-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:157) ~[camel-spring-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.ndb.ndbdemo.NdbdemoApplication.main(NdbdemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This component does not support producer.
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:52) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:67) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:101) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.channel.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:143) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:87) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:154) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:334) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:184) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This component does not support producer.
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpEndpoint.createProducer(JettyHttpEndpoint.java:95) ~[camel-jetty-common-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.createAsyncProducer(DefaultEndpoint.java:200) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:230) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:101) ~[camel-api-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1459) ~[camel-base-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60) ~[camel-support-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there any other alternative out there?

Answer (score 0):

jetty component doesnt support producer, you can just get request with jetty you cannot call other endpoint jetty is Only consumer is supported component your shared document so old. use netty-http for proxy server

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/netty-http-component.html

```
from("netty-http:proxy://0.0.0.0:8080")
    .toD("netty-http:"
        + "${headers." + Exchange.HTTP_SCHEME + "}://"
        + "${headers." + Exchange.HTTP_HOST + "}:"
        + "${headers." + Exchange.HTTP_PORT + "}")
```